# How to do i prove that this inequality is valid in the given set?

Tags: inequality, optimization, linear-programming, binary-programming

How do I prove that $$z_1 + x_{12} + x_{22} + x_{13} + x_{23} + z_4 \geq 2$$
is a valid inequality for my constraints:
\begin{align}
x_{11} + x_{12} + x_{13} &\geq 1 \tag1\label1\\
x_{12} + x_{13} + x_{14} &\geq 1 \tag2\label2\\
x_{21} + x_{22} + x_{23} + x_{24} &\geq 1 \tag3\label3\\
x_{ij} &\leq z_j &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$} \tag4\label4\\
x_{ij}, z_j &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$}
\end{align}

I have tried several ways but the closest I have gotten is by taking \eqref{1} + \eqref{2} + 2\eqref{3} to get:
$$x_{11} + 2x_{21} + 2x_{12} + 2x_{22} + 2x_{13} + 2x_{23} + x_{14} + 2x_{24} \geq 4$$ then replacing $x_{11}, x_{21}$ with $z_1$ and $x_{14}, x_{24}$ with $z_4$ and then dividing by 2 which gives the invalid inequality:
$$\frac32 z_1 + x_{12} + x_{22} + x_{13} + x_{23} + \frac32 z_4 \geq 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Adding up the first three constraints, $-x_{ij} + z_j \ge 0$ for $(i,j)\in\{1,2\}\times\{1,4\}$, and the lower bounds $x_{22} \ge 0$ and $x_{23} \ge 0$ yields
$$2x_{12} + 2x_{13} + 2x_{22} + 2x_{23} + 2z_1 + 2z_4 \ge 3.$$
Now divide both sides by $2$ to obtain
$$x_{12} + x_{13} + x_{22} + x_{23} + z_1 + z_4 \ge \frac{3}{2}.$$
Because the left-hand side is integer-valued, you can replace the right-hand side with $\lceil 3/2 \rceil = 2$, yielding the desired inequality.